# cloning the props that we receive in this.props in reactjs when using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I receive certain data coming from the global store and I need to make add the certain property to the props coming.
Going by the redux principles, I should not change anything directly in the this. props but I can definitely clone it so that changes get reflected but only in the cloned copy instead of this .props.
How can be acheived
I am adding a piece of code to make things more clear.

```
 if(this.props
        && this.props.student
        && this.props.student.students
        && this.props.student.students.data



    ){
        cloneddata=this.props.student.students.data;
         console.log("cloneddata",cloneddata);

            console.log("noddie2",this.props.student.students.data);
            if( cloneddata.data && cloneddata.data.length>0){
                cloneddata.data.map((item)=>{
                    if(item.attendance===undefined){
                        item.attendance=[
                            {
                                status:"a",
                                studentId:item._id
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                })
            }
            console.log("clonedata after",cloneddata);
```

What I see is that even after taking everything in a variable clonedata,I still get  newly added things in this.props.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it is a good idea, but you can try this:

```
cloneddata = this.props.student.students.data.map(item => ({...item}))
```

This way it creates shallow copy of `item`. In case you need deep copy you can use smth like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep

Answer (score 0):

Since you assign `this.props.student.students.data` directly to `cloneddata`, it is assingned by Reference and hence any change in the cloneddata is also reflected in the props

You need to create a copy of your data instead

```
 if(this.props
    && this.props.student
    && this.props.student.students
    && this.props.student.students.data



){

        console.log("noddie2",this.props.student.students.data);
        if( this.props.student.students.data.data && this.props.student.students.data.data.length>0){
            cloneddata = this.props.student.students.data.data.map((item)=>{
                if(item.attendance===undefined){
                    return {
                      attendance: [
                        {
                            status:"a",
                            studentId:item._id
                        }
                      ]
                   }
                } 
                return { ...item }
            })
        }
        console.log("clonedata after",cloneddata);
```

Comment: Ok i will just try this and see .

Comment: i simply get cloneddata undefined at the last console log

Comment: did you write `cloneddata = cloneddata.data.map((item)=>{`

Comment: Yeah .But where does that data come from in cloneddata.data?

Comment: Ahh, sorry my mistake, it should be `this.props.student.students.data.data`

Comment: that still does return anything.